# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context Alamofire Request Error

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire, wordpress-rest-api

I am very new to Xcode and trying to fetch data from my WordPress website in SwiftUI using rest api. I have got code from internet , I have installed these pod's

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

Imported all pods in homeController and using this code to fetch data.

```swift
Alamofire.request("\(urlPage)\(page)").responseJSON { response in
    if let data = response.result.value {
        let json2 = JSON(data)
        self.moreDataNum = json2["count"].intValue
        if self.dataArray?.isEmpty == false {
            self.dataArray.append(contentsOf: json2["posts"].arrayValue)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            // ...
```

I am getting this error..

[open image to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFCgE.png)

please help me ..

Comment: If you are new to Xcode consider to load the third-party libraries with Swift Package Manager rather than with tedious CocoaPods. It's built-in and much easier to use. And drop outdated SwiftyJSON in favor of Codable which AlamoFire supports out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use latest version of alamofire 5.5.0 then use below code :---

```
let musicAPI = "https://staging.mywowmemories.com/api/get-background-music"

AF.request(musicAPI, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
          
         if let result = response.value as? NSDictionary {
                

         }
}
```

Comment: `responseJSON` is deprecated and don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift.